# Template contents are not available although template file is loaded

Tags: requirejs

I have this Backbone view defined:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "main", "text!templates/loginViewTemplate.html"], 
  function($, Backbone, loginViewTemplate) {
      var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

        render: function() {
              console.log(loginViewTemplate);             
              this.template = _.template(loginViewTemplate, {});              
              $(this.el).html(this.template);
              return this;   
        },

        // ...
     });
 });
```

But the console.log statement is "undefined", nothing gets rendered. Although I can see a request to the `loginViewTemplate.html` file in the console. What am I missing?

Comment: It's the factory function parameter list that needs fixing; currently: "jquery" -> $, "backbone" -> Backbone, "main" -> loginViewTemplate, "text!templates/loginViewTemplate.html" -> (nothing). The fact that `loginViewTemplate` is undefined indicates the `main` module doesn't return anything meaningful (not a module at all?).

Comment: That is correct. I am VERY new to Require.js (like.. yesterday) and so, my original javascript file was not a module at this time (some configuration methods and helper methods in it). Now I defined it as a module, so I can pass it correctly to the factory function. But what about jquery-cookie for example? When I want to use `$.cookie` I have to define `jquery-cookie` as a dependency, but cannot pass it to the function!? That confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

After getting off the screen for some minutes, I figured out, that the order of dependency declaration is important.

Making the first line look like this solved it:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "text!templates/loginViewTemplate.html", "main"],
  function($, Backbone, loginViewTemplate) {
```

Comment: The order itself is not important but a dependency is not available if a reference to it is not passed to the callback function. To avoid problems when more dependencies are added I'd suggest making the function parameters `($, Backbone, loginViewTemplate, main)` even if `main` is not used (...but that indicates it's a _side-effect_ dependency?).